# Check the presence of a number in a very large array quickly (C#)

Tags: c#

I got a problem when playing with the tutorial of a codingame.

The goal is to check if an `int` exists in an `int` array.

The problem is, the tutorial has this requirement:

The solution works in a reasonable time with one million items

I tried many different methods like LINQ, `Dictionary`, binary search, exponential search, and some other methods but still failed for this.

Anyone can tell me the fastest method to solve this problem?

Comment: How long do each of the methods you have tried take?

Comment: Do we know anything about the integers and the value to search? Do they have a range smaller than `int.MinValue` through `int.MaxValue`? Is the array already sorted? If not, can we use what we know about the contents to sort if quicker than average? Is the search value "special" in a way that allows us to go through the array faster than one element at a time? Without any particular context, you can't do much better than a linear search, but if there's a trick, a gotcha, a shortcut, all that might change.

Comment: @JeroenMostert ...making this question pretty unclear.

Comment: @HimBromBeere: yes -- I'm exercising my prerogative to "use comments to ask for more information".

Comment: we still miss any additional information in what **exactly** you´ve tried and in which way "it failed".

Comment: Thanks all. All details I can get from codingame are here: 1. all items are integers arrandged in ascending order 2. the array can contain up to 1 mil items 3. the array is never null.

Comment: Yes it looks really unclear but this is what I can only know from the question. If possible please also tell me your assumption for the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finding a number in an arbitrary array will inevitably take `O(N)` (linear to input) time (as you cannot make any assumptions about what might be on any given index, so you just have to visit them all in the worst case).

The situation improves when the array is sorted - in this case, you can use Binary search to find the value in `O(log n)` time. This is built-in .NET using `Array.BinarySearch` method. This is the best solution if you just need to search for the value once.

```
if ( Array.BinarySearch(data, number) >= 0 )
{
   //found
}
```

Finally you are going to search the array multiple times, a better option is to first create a `HashSet<int>` from the array. In this case any subsequent query will return in average `O(1)` time (constant). In this case you however need to remember, that creating the `HashSet<int>` will itself take `O(n)` time as well as memory. This solution is only worth using if you will be asked to search for the value multiple times. If you search only once, then you are better off just going through the array once in `O(N)` and you will also save memory.

```
var lookup = new HashSet<int>(data);
if ( lookup.Contains(number) )
{
   //do something
}
```

Comment: @HimBromBeere Hope it is more specific now.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the `>` comparison :-D . I accidentally did not press the <kbd>=</kbd> key enough

Comment: @MartinZikmund Thanks! Your answer already solved my problem(which cost me like 20 trials already). I implemented the binary search myself (copied the simple codes online actually) and failed. Just now I tried Array.BinarySearch and it succeeded. Can anyone tell the reason?

Comment: We can check that too :-) . Write a new question and post the code you have written yourself and post a comment with the link to the new question here :-)